# Can't connect to mysql from applications other than terminal

Tags: mysql

I can't connect to my local sql server from DataGrip. But it works fine directly from the terminal.

Anyone that can see what I'm doing wrong? 
I haven't set any password and I've tried both without password and with my Ubuntu user password.

I get this error When trying to connect from DataGrip:

```
The specified user/password combination is rejected: [28000][1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost
```

It works fine from the terminal like this:

```
jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ sudo mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 16
Server version: 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: You must learn to not use `sudo` unnecessarily.

Comment: @fkraiem Good catch.  It turns out the `sudo` was the culprit.  It was the only reason the terminal access was working.  Mysql had inadvertently been installed without a password.  An attempt to access it normally validated the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mysql users are granted access based on where the connection is coming from.  By default the root access is restricted to:

- 127.0.0.1
- localhost

The program you are using to connect is not indentifying itself as **127.0.0.1** or **localhost**.  You will have to verify the IP access it's being identified as, then add that to your grant table.

You can also, alternatively (**highly insecure and should only be used for testing and to validate the program will work knowing the proper IP**) grant access to any ip by adding **%** to the grant table for root.  This can at least be a temporary access while you work to identify the IP address being used for access.

These are command variations to grant an IP address:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'computer.host.com';
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.101';
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

***Important!**

The **%** wild card should not be used, especially for `root`.  It's mentioned for **information** and **testing** only.  It would make your computer become vulnerable to any computer hacker from anywhere in the world.*

For security you might consider setting up a different name from root to give this access to and leave the actual **root** user more limited to where connections can be made.

You also may have to comment out the `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` configuration in your **my.cnf** file.

### From the **Phpmyadmin** GUI

Alternatively from Phpmyadmin perform these steps:

```
Phpmyadmin -> (click) Users -> Add user -> (For the user root Click on)
Edit Privileges ->  (Scroll to) Host -> (Type in the desired IP address) ->
(click) Go.
```

**Update:**

The OP's problem was resolved (via chat) by setting a password to Mysql.  It had originally been installed with a blank password.  That is why the only way to access mysql was to use `sudo`.  After properly adding a password to mysql the access worked by default using the default localhost/127.0.0.1 for the access and the Datagrip application.

Comment: I get this error: `ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table` when running this `mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.72';`

Comment: @Jeggy The "`%`" will work.  But I just tested.  The IP address is giving the error message. Give me a minute to figure out why the ipaddress isn't taking and update my answer.

Comment: not for me :/ I'm getting the same error `Can't find any matching row in the user table`

Comment: I'm configuring a resolution to my answer now...  After testing and checking grammar I'll post it... in about 5 minutes.

Comment: @Jeggy I tested the steps from Phpadmin... I tested the IP address, the hostname and the wild card.  They all work.  I'll still investigate why the cli fails and update that information to the answer.

Comment: I don't have phpmyadmin. I installed mysql with `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51264/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-jeggy).

Comment: `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';` is asking to be hacked.  The same with phpmyadmin; I don't recommend it unless you want to increase your risk of being compromised.

Comment: @SamGleske I hope my message was clear to anyone reading that the **`%`** wildcard is insecure and was only mentioned as a test to verify mysql works while looking for the proper IP address coming from the application.  Also, if you look at the details in the discussion you'll see that the problem was resolved using `localhost`.  I'll update the answer with details from the discussion link soon.  I'll put the **insecure** reference in bold to make it clearer that it shouldn't be done.

Comment: No worries L.D. I just wanted to make it clear from a security perspective.